# Compile time constants in inner classes

Tags: java, inner-classes

Why this type of static members is allowed in inner classes? I mean what it give us? I can only imagine something like this:

```
public class Math {
    public class Trigonometry {
        static final int SIN_90_DEGREE = 1;
        //...
    }
}
```

But why any static field is prohibited but compile-time constants is allowed i still can't clearly understand.

Comment: Static fields *aren't* prohibited from static inner classes.

Comment: I've read these posts. But i am asking why compile time constant is allowed.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be allowed?

Comment: Because it's constant at compile time and its value cannot be modified. Thus, there won't be any problem when using this variable.

Comment: @Mark Peters sorry, fixed. But now it become even harder to use.

Comment: Wht it's duplicate? I asked about compile-time constant. Why language allows it in this place?